# How would I scale my buttons and my header with the window size?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS and I started creating a website with the help of YouTube and Stack Overflow. I pretty much finished but the only issue is that my header and buttons do not scale with the window size. Here are different window sizes: [regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBMrY.jpg), [iPhone 12 Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqet8.jpg), [iPhone XR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHbWf.jpg). I would like all of my windows to resemble the regular window but I could not find a solution that I could understand. Does anyone know how to make it so that the buttons and header would size accordingly to the window size that it is in?

This is my CSS and HTML code (sorry in advance if this looks like a mess):

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
body{
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}
button{
    margin: 7px;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
h1{
    color: #FAF9F6;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-80%);
}
.btn{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-54%,-45%);
}
button{
    background-color: black;
    color: #FAF9F6;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    border: .5px solid #f53b57;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: .6s;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(1);
}
button:focus{
    outline: none;
}
button:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: .5s;
    filter: blur(30px);
    transform: translate(-130px) skewX(-15deg);
}
button:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 30px;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(30px);
    transform: translate(-100px) scaleX(-15deg);
}
button:hover{
    color:#f53b57;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
button:hover:before{
    transform: translate(300px) skewX(-15deg);
    opacity: .6;
    transition: .7s;
}
button:hover:after{
    transform: translate(300px) skewX(-15deg);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .7s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Julian Sanchez</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4ce3863cee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    .button__text{
        height: 100%;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .button__icon{
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 5px;
        font-size: smaller;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Julian Sanchez</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="btn">
            <ul>  
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Instagram</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Twitter</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Facebook</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Youtube</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">LinkedIn</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">GitHub</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Email</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <button type="button" class="button">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-discord"></i>
                            <span class="button__text">Discord</span>
                        </button>    
                 </li>
                 <li>
                         <button type="button" class="button">
                             <i class="fa-brands fa-xbox"></i>
                             <span class="button__text">Xbox</span>
                         </button>    
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are many, many ways to achieve this. Since you're using a fixed width of 400px, I'd consider using `max-width` with a percentage value so it doesn't overflow - e.g. `max-width: 100%;` combined with `padding: 0px 20px;`, both CSS-properties on the `button`-element

Comment: Look into using relative units for everything, in your case sizing everything in relation to various or vmin might be appropriate.. If you use px units they will not scale nicely on different window sizes.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to use `position: fixed` and `position: absolute` for laying everything out. I would make the `<ul`> a flex container and set the `flex-direction` to column. Then, `align-items` center. Below is the updated code.

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}
button{
    margin: 7px;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1{
    color: #FAF9F6;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

button{
    background-color: black;
    color: #FAF9F6;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    border: .5px solid #f53b57;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: transform .6s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
button:hover{
    color:#f53b57;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.03);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

   li {
     width: 90%;
   }

  button{
    width: 100%;
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>Julian Sanchez</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="btn">
          <ul>  
              <li>
                  <button type="button" class="button">
                      <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                      <span class="button__text">Instagram</span>
                  </button>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <button type="button" class="button">
                      <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                      <span class="button__text">Twitter</span>
                  </button>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <button type="button" class="button">
                      <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                      <span class="button__text">Facebook</span>
                  </button>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <button type="button" class="button">
                      <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
                      <span class="button__text">Youtube</span>
                  </button>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <button type="button" class="button">
                      <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
                      <span class="button__text">LinkedIn</span>
                  </button>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <button type="button" class="button">
                      <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
                      <span class="button__text">GitHub</span>
                  </button>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <button type="button" class="button">
                      <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
                      <span class="button__text">Email</span>
                  </button>
              </li>
              <li>
                      <button type="button" class="button">
                          <i class="fa-brands fa-discord"></i>
                          <span class="button__text">Discord</span>
                      </button>    
               </li>
               <li>
                       <button type="button" class="button">
                           <i class="fa-brands fa-xbox"></i>
                           <span class="button__text">Xbox</span>
                       </button>    
               </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because absolute units are used in the height and width of buttons.

```
width: 400px;
height: 70px;
```

Replacing them with relative units like `%` , `vh` , `vw` will make them relative to  their parent (in case of `%` ) and browser window size (in case of `vh` , `vw`).

Just to illustrate this I have added some code at the end of your css code, which will overwrite your absolute unit code. Run this code and resize window, and buttons will also resize according to the size of browser window. So using relative units will solve this issue.

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
body{
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}
button{
    margin: 7px;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
h1{
    color: #FAF9F6;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    left: 50%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-80%);
}
.btn{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-54%,-45%);
}
button{
    background-color: black;
    color: #FAF9F6;
    width: 400px;
    height: 70px;
    border: .5px solid #f53b57;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: .6s;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(1);
}
button:focus{
    outline: none;
}
button:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: .5s;
    filter: blur(30px);
    transform: translate(-130px) skewX(-15deg);
}
button:after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 30px;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(30px);
    transform: translate(-100px) scaleX(-15deg);
}
button:hover{
    color:#f53b57;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.03);
}
button:hover:before{
    transform: translate(300px) skewX(-15deg);
    opacity: .6;
    transition: .7s;
}
button:hover:after{
    transform: translate(300px) skewX(-15deg);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .7s;
}

/* code added by me to demonstrate relative units*/

button {
   width: 50vw;
   height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Julian Sanchez</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4ce3863cee.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    .button__text{
        height: 100%;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .button__icon{
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0 5px;
        font-size: smaller;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Julian Sanchez</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="btn">
            <ul>  
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Instagram</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Twitter</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Facebook</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Youtube</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">LinkedIn</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">GitHub</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button type="button" class="button">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
                        <span class="button__text">Email</span>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <button type="button" class="button">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-discord"></i>
                            <span class="button__text">Discord</span>
                        </button>    
                 </li>
                 <li>
                         <button type="button" class="button">
                             <i class="fa-brands fa-xbox"></i>
                             <span class="button__text">Xbox</span>
                         </button>    
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```